# TakeWhile results in type mismatch

Tags: scala

I am trying to read an input stream in chunks:

```
import scala.io.Source

// val in = Source.stdin.mkString("")
val in = Source.fromFile("/shared/american.txt").getLines.mkString("")
var ptr = 0
val out = Stream.continually {
  val ix = math.min(ptr+80,in.length)
  val ret = in.substring(ptr, ix)
  ptr = ix
  ret
}

out: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[String] = Stream(Unmentionable has an enthusiastic 35% of the popular vote. I discount the other 10% or s, ?)
```

But what is the syntax for `take` in chunks? I tried:

```
val chunks = out.takeWhile( ptr < in.length)


<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean
 required: String => Boolean
           val ret = out.takeWhile( ptr < in.length)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish?  If you are just trying to break a string (file) into chunks you could use the `.grouped()` or `.groupBy()` functions.

As for your current error, the compiler tells you what you need to do.   You're giving a Boolean:

```
val chunks = out.takeWhile(ptr < in.length) // ptr < in.length evaluates to a boolean
```

but you need to give a function that takes a String and returns a Boolean:

```
val chunks = out.takeWhile(s => ptr < s.length)  // Something like this
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading a file in 80 character chunks?  How 'bout this?

```
val in = io.Source.fromFile("file.txt").mkString.grouped(80)
while (in.hasNext) {
  // in.next is your chunk
}
```

Comment: grouped(n) will do the same thing as sliding(n,n)

Comment: Oops.  Missed that. Thanks.